# How to select an item from a listview and pass the values over to another page for edit or delete

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

below is a draft code that I wrote for selecting an item on a listview and passing it over to another page to edit. Ok right now in the listview, 1 item consists of ID, Body Temp, Heart Rate and BMI. Now when I select them they should pass values over via intent to another page whereby I can either delete the entire item, so it will be totally removed from the database OR I can edit body temp, heart rate and BMI. The ID I can just leave it as a textview . But right now I cannot even select the item for it to pass values to another page. please advise.

```
/*Codes for selecting and passing values to edit page*/
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
             String BTemp = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
             String HRate = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
             String Bmi = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

             Cursor data = dbhelper.getRecID(BTemp, HRate, Bmi);
             int recID = -1;
             while(data.moveToNext()){
                 recID = data.getInt(0);
             }
             if(recID > -1){

                 Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(ViewRecords.this, EditDel.class);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",recID);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("Body Temperature",BTemp);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("Heart Rate",HRate);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("BMI",Bmi);
                 startActivity(editScreenIntent);
             }
             else{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No ID Associated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }



 /* DatabaseHelper.java*/
     public Cursor getRecID(String BTemp, String Hrate, String Bmi){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                    " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + BTemp + "' AND " + COL3 + " = '" + Hrate + "' AND " + COL4 + " = '" + Bmi +"'";
            Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `cursor.moveToFirst();` before using `cursor.moveToNext()` in `while(data.moveToNext())` ??

Comment: And don't you think BTemp, HRate and Bmi are exact same values as in `String BTemp = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
             String HRate = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
             String Bmi = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();` or I'm missing something??

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar yeah thats my concern actually I can just make it 
`String id = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();`  and I can change to  `Cursor data = dbhelper.getRecID(id);` and I can change my database helper to public `Cursor getRecID(String id)` but what about my intent ? `editScreenIntent.putExtra("Body Temperature",BTemp);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("Heart Rate",HRate);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("BMI",Bmi);` They Btemp, Hrate and Bmi comes from  `Cursor data = dbhelper.getRecID(BTemp, HRate, Bmi)`

Comment: But if you have the id then you can easily extract the respective detail (i.e. BTemp, HRate, Bmi) from the database using the id as `select co2, col3, col4 from yourTableName where col1=id;`. Using this query, you'll have your required three values and then you can pass them with your intent.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar alright I will give it a try. I update here if I encounter any problem